# How can I spawn a new process and quit from a node.js script?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I have a nodeJS command line script which interacts with a website using phantomJS via casperJS/spookyJS. A redirect event is stopping my process from working correctly. How would I respond to the redirect, spawn a new process and kill the process which has been redirected?

e.g:

```
spooky.on('navigation.requested', function(url, navigationType, navigationLocked, isMainFrame){
    if (url.toString().match(/(http:\/\/url(.|\n)to(.|\n)match\/client\/authentication\/login)/i)) {
        utils.log('redirect happened');
        //get my own process id, launch a new process, get that id.
        //kill this id?
    }
});
```

How would I:

- Get the process Id of the currently running node process (the one
  running the above code - process A)?
- Spawn a new node process (process B) which would be independent of
  process A
- Kill Process A

Process B should continue to run even when process A has terminated. Would I need a third node process (C) to manage process A and B?

Answer (score 0):

use ['detached' option](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in `child_process.spawn()` You may also want to detach tty from process (use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) utility)

Comment: Thanks. If I kill the parent process, will the child process continue to run?

Comment: yes: `If the detached option is set, the child process will be made the leader of a new process group. This makes it possible for the child to continue running after the parent exits.`